# Updated: Getting a Toast for a ListView with Images on Android App

Tags: android, listview, android-arrayadapter, android-toast

For the below, I've added the following toast:

```
public void Toast (View v) {
    Toast.makeText(this, "Test", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
}
```

It works but obviously all it does is display "Test" for everything.  I thought I'd be able to do 'this.dogTitles' or 'this.dogDescriptions' but it won't let me.

Can someone please explain why?  I've placed it in the onCreate method.

Thanks

I am having trouble working out how to program a toast whenever a list item (row) is clicked.

I can do toasts for simple programs but am struggling to work it out for something like this because of the array adapters.

My code is below.

Thanks in advance.

```
package lab.mad.cct.c3375331task2;

import android.content.Context;
import android.content.res.Resources;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;
import android.widget.ImageView;
import android.widget.ListView;
import android.widget.TextView;

public class Task2Activity extends AppCompatActivity {

ListView list;
String [] dogTitles;
String [] dogDescriptions;
int[] images = {R.drawable.husky, R.drawable.pug, R.drawable.yorkshire_terrier, R.drawable.french_bulldog,
R.drawable.border_collie, R.drawable.great_dane, R.drawable.staffordshire_bull_terrier, R.drawable.golden_retriever,
R.drawable.german_shepherd, R.drawable.doberman};

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_task2);

    Resources res = getResources();
    dogTitles = res.getStringArray(R.array.titles);
    dogDescriptions = res.getStringArray(R.array.descriptions);

    list = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.listView);
    dogAdapter adapter = new dogAdapter(this, dogTitles, images, dogDescriptions);
    list.setAdapter(adapter);
}
}

class dogAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<String>
{
    Context context;
int[] images;
String[] titleArray;
String[] descriptionArray;
dogAdapter(Context c, String[] titles, int imgs[], String[] desc)
{
    super(c, R.layout.single_row, R.id.largeText, titles);
    this.context = c;
    this.images = imgs;
    this.titleArray = titles;
    this.descriptionArray = desc;
}

class MyViewHolder
{
    ImageView myImage;
    TextView myTitle;
    TextView myDescription;
    MyViewHolder(View v)
    {
        myImage = (ImageView) v.findViewById(R.id.imageView);
        myTitle = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.largeText);
        myDescription = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.smallText);
    }
}

@Override
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
    View row = convertView;
    MyViewHolder holder = null;
    if (row == null) {
        LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) context.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
        row = inflater.inflate(R.layout.single_row, parent, false);
        holder = new MyViewHolder(row);
        row.setTag(holder);
        Log.d("dogs", "Creating a new row");
            }
    else {
        holder = (MyViewHolder) row.getTag();
        Log.d("dogs", "Recycling stuff");
    }
    //ImageView myImage = (ImageView) row.findViewById(R.id.imageView);
    //TextView myTitle = (TextView) row.findViewById(R.id.largeText);
    //TextView myDescription = (TextView) row.findViewById(R.id.smallText);

    holder.myImage.setImageResource(images[position]);
    holder.myTitle.setText(titleArray[position]);
    holder.myDescription.setText(descriptionArray[position]);

    row.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            Toast toast = new Toast(getContext());
            toast.setDuration(Toast.LENGTH_LONG);
            toast.show();
        }
    });

    return row;
}
}
```

Comment: `this` refers to the current object and changes what it is referring to depending on where it is called. I've updated my answer to show how you can get the values from the arrays but you can also get the values from the adapter if necessary.

Answer (score 0):

Inside the onCreate after you set the adapter place an OnClickListener after from list.

```
list.setOnClickListener
```

then inside the onClick add a Toast like you would normally.

if you want it from a specific widget within the row use that widget the same was you would the list. Do this in the adapter, though. Do it after your holder.myDescription.setText

```
textView.setOnClickListener
```

and on its onCreate place your toast inside.

Comment: I didn't think it was that simple though @AdamGardner.  I want it to be able to click anywhere on the row to get the toast.  By doing it the way I know, I would have to use one of the text boxes or the image.  How would I do that?

Comment: it is, @PhilAdams. You can setOnClickListener to the row, the list, or individual widgets that make up your row if you want.

Answer (score 0):

You'll be able to specifically handle per row a toast by doing the following in your `getView()` method of the ArrayAdapter

```
row.setOnClicklistener(new View.OnClickListener() {
   @Override
   public void onClick(View view) {
      //display toast here  
   }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Inside your onCreate add an `OnItemClickListener` to your `ListView`. `OnIemClickListener` is built into ListView to provide click interaction with each row item in your ListView.

Inside your `onCreate`:

```
list = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.listView);
dogAdapter adapter = new dogAdapter(this, dogTitles, images, dogDescriptions);
list.setAdapter(adapter);

list.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener(){
    @Override
    public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id){

        // Use the clicked item's position to get the corresponding values
        // from arrays, adapter, etc.
        Toast.makeText(getContext(), dogTitles[position] + " " + dogDescriptions[position], Toast.LENGTH_LONG)
               .show();
    }
});
```

Comment: I struggle to understand where to place this as I've tried several things but to no avail

Comment: @PhilAdams Place `list.setOnItemClickListener()` after `list.setAdapter()`

Answer (score 0):

```
row.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        Toast.makeText(context, ""+position, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You havent assigned any view to Toast Your click is working but toast is not displaying.
**simple way to display toast**

```
Toast.makeText(this, "Android Simple Toast", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
```

**According to your code you have to set one view to toast like this**
*toast.xml*

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:id="@+id/toast_layout_root"
android:orientation="horizontal"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="fill_parent"
android:padding="10dp"
android:background="#DAAA" >

<TextView android:id="@+id/text"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:textColor="#FFF" />
```

*Then in your on click*

```
LayoutInflater inflater = getLayoutInflater();
View layout = inflater.inflate(R.layout.toast_layout,
                               (ViewGroup) findViewById(R.id.toast_layout_root));
TextView text = (TextView) layout.findViewById(R.id.text);
text.setText("Hello! This is a custom toast!");

Toast toast = new Toast(getApplicationContext());
toast.setGravity(Gravity.CENTER_VERTICAL, 0, 0);
toast.setDuration(Toast.LENGTH_LONG);
toast.setView(layout);//this you missed
toast.show();
```